# Associating open graph action with multiple objects & caption template

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

Currently I am building a site with a Facebook Open Graph integration.

One complication I have is since user can do seemingly similar actions to different objects on our site, it is easy for us to define different action for each similar actions. However, it seems like Facebook is not allowing ( or at least not liking ) for one site to have multiple similarly looking actions.

For instance, let's assume that user can both 'buy' a car, and 'buy' an insurance in our site.
Although, on surface, these two action look similar, because their context is different we want to show different content - more specifically different caption - for each action that is postsed.

Simple way to implement this will be defining two actions,
   'BuyCar' <---> associated with Car
   'BuyInsurance' <---> associated with Insurance
and let them have distinctive caption template.

However, as I mentioned earlier, since Facebook does not allow multiple similar actions to be defined within a site, I should be defining.
    'Buy' <----> associated with [Car, Insurance]
    where this action always have only one property defined. (either Car or Insurance)
Downside of having these type of action is, due to limitation in current cation's template language (lacks conditional statement), I am not able to produce different caption effectively without knowing which property is set.

How should I be handling this issue?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the captions do need to be something generic that will work for all connected object types. But you could use filters to defined separate aggregations for each object type.

Just add an additional parameter to all of your objects and set the value of that parameter as an aggregation filter?